# Why indexPath.row doesn't work here?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I am adding values from the first TableView var savedUrls to the first section of var detailsInSection in second TableView. In prepareForSegue, Xcode shows " unresolved Identifier for 'indexPath'. How should I revise the codes?

In first View Controller:

```
var folderNames = [String]()

var savedUrls = [String]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let url = savedUrls[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueToDetailsTable, sender: url)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == segueToDetailsTable {

        let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController

        detailsVC.detailsInSection[0].append(savedUrls[indexPath.row])

    }   
}
```

In Second View Controller:

```
var sectionTitles = ["WebSite", "Date Saved", "Document Used","Add Notes"]

var detailsInSection = [[String]() , [NSDate]() , [AnyObject]() , String]() ]
```

Comment: `detailsVC.detailsInSection[0].append(sender)`? In `prepareForSegue()` you are using `indexPath` that is not existing in this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexPath` is not a variable defined or passed into `prepareForSegue`. You are on the right track though. Since you pass the `url` as the sender in `performSegue...`, you don't need an `indexPath` to reference the `url`. You can check that the `sender` was a `String` and use `sender` as the `url` that was selected.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let url = savedUrls[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueToDetailsTable, sender: url)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let url = sender as? String where segue.identifier == segueToDetailsTable {

        let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController

        detailsVC.detailsInSection[0].append(url)

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index path in `didSelectRow...` as `sender` parameter and get the url later

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueToDetailsTable, sender: indexPath)
}
```

---

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == segueToDetailsTable {
     let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
     let url = savedUrls[indexPath.row]
     let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController

     detailsVC.detailsInSection[0].append(url)
  }
}
```